# Trying to store sequences as a linked list inside a linked list - Java

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

so this is for a class project and I've run into a problem that I've no idea how I caused. I'm writing a method that is suppose to take a sequence of RNA or DNA, parse it into a char array verify that all the character are appropriate for the sequence type then turn the array into a singly linked list where each node contains one letter, then i want to pass that list into a node of fList the outer linked list.

```
    //if sequence is valid fill frag with base sequence and pass the list to 
    //fragment list (fList) at position of insert
    if(validSeq){
        fList.moveTo(pos);
        frag.moveToStart();
        for(int count = 0;count < sequence.length(); count++){            
            frag.insert(seq[count]);
        }

        fList.insert(frag);
        System.out.print(fList.getValue());
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("Invalid Sequence: not stored   ");
    }
```

but the output I've been getting is:

- [cccccccccccccccccccccc] for attacgatctgcacaagatcct
- [tttttttt] for ggggtttt
- [aaaaaa] for aaccaa

it seems to be repeating the second to last letter for the whole thing but I've no idea why. I'm sure what causing it is in the above block from the method. First time posting here so sorry if I'm not doing this correctly or missing something obvious.

edit: this is the singly linked list I'm using

```
    /**  
 * Singly Linked list implementation which
 * uses package private {@link Node} to store node values.
 * @see List
 */
public class SLList<E> implements List<E> {
  private transient Node<E> head;      // Pointer to list header
  private transient Node<E> tail;      // Pointer to last element
  private transient Node<E> curr;      // Access to current element
  private transient int listSize;      // Size of list

  /**
   * Create a new empty singly linked list.
   */
  public SLList() { 
    curr = tail = new Node<E>(null);
    head = new Node<E>(tail);
    listSize = 0;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public void clear() {
    curr = tail = new Node<E>(null);
    head = new Node<E>(tail);
    listSize = 0;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public boolean insert(E it) {
    curr.setNext(new Node<E>(curr.element(), curr.next()));
    curr.setElement(it);
    if (tail == curr) {
      tail = curr.next();
    }
    listSize++;
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   * This append operatoin will not increment the current element reference.
   */
  @Override
  public boolean append(E it) {
    tail.setNext(new Node<E>(null));
    tail.setElement(it);
    tail = tail.next();
    listSize++;
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public E remove () {
    if (curr == tail) {
      return null;          // Nothing to remove
    }
    E it = curr.element();                  // Remember value
    curr.setElement(curr.next().element()); // Pull forward the next element
    if (curr.next() == tail) {
      tail = curr;   // Removed last, move tail
    }
    curr.setNext(curr.next().next());       // Point around unneeded link
    listSize--;                             // Decrement element count
    return it;                              // Return value
  }

  /**
   * Move the current element reference to the head of the list.
   */
  @Override
  public void moveToStart() { 
    curr = head; 
  }

  /**
   * Move the current element reference to the tail of the list.
   */
  @Override
  public void moveToEnd() { 
    curr = tail; 
  }

  /**
   * Move the current element reference one step closer to the
   * list head.
   * If the current element is already at the head, this method
   * does nothing.
   * <dl>
   * <  dt>Note:</dt>
   *   <dd>As this is a singly linked list, the {@link #prev} operation 
   *   can be expensive - up to O(n^2) on large lists.</dd>
   * </dl>
   * @return the value of the previous node in the list.
   */
  @Override
  public E prev() {
    if (head == curr) {
      return null; // No previous element
    }
    Node<E> temp = head;
    // March down list until we find the previous element
    while (temp.next() != curr) {
      temp = temp.next();
    }
    curr = temp;
    return curr.element();
  }

  /**
   * Move the current element reference one step closer to the
   * list tail.
   * If the current element is already at the tail, this method
   * returns null.
   * @return the value of the next node in the list.
   */
  @Override
  public E next() { 
    if (curr != tail) {
      curr = curr.next(); 
    }
    return curr.element();
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public int length() { 
    return listSize; 
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public int position() {
    Node<E> temp = head;
    int i;
    for (i=0; curr != temp; i++) {
      temp = temp.next();
    }
    return i;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   * @return null if pos does not refer to a valid position in the list
   */
  @Override
  public E moveTo(int pos) {
    if ((pos < 0) || (pos > listSize)) {
      return null;
    }
    curr = head;
    for(int i=0; i<pos; i++) {
      curr = curr.next();
    }
    return curr.element();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public boolean isAtEnd() { 
    return curr.next() == tail; 
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   * Note that null gets returned if the current reference is at the tail
   */
  @Override
  public E getValue() {
    return curr.element();
  }

  /**
   * Display the string representation of the value stored within 
   * each element in the list.
   * The entire list is bounded by square brackets.
   */
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    curr = head;
    for(int i=0; i<listSize; i++) {
      sb.append(curr.next().toString());
    }
    return "[" + sb.toString() + "]";
  }

}
```

edit: this is the entire method cause me trouble

```
//sends sequence to flist after verifying their validity
    public static void sendToFlist(String sequence, sequenceType stype, int pos, 
            SLList fList){

        char[] seq = new char[sequence.length()];
        boolean validSeq = true;
        SLList frag = new SLList();
        frag.clear();

        //turn sequence into an array for validity parsing
        for(int count = 0;count < sequence.length(); count++){
            seq[count] = sequence.charAt(count);                       
        }

        //check sequence validity based on sequence type enum
        switch(stype){
                case RNA: 
                    for(int count = 0;count < sequence.length(); count++){
                        if(!(Character.valueOf(seq[count]).equals('a'))&&
                                !(Character.valueOf(seq[count]).equals('g'))&&
                                !(Character.valueOf(seq[count]).equals('c'))&&
                                !(Character.valueOf(seq[count]).equals('u'))){
                          validSeq = false;
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case DNA: 
                    for(int count = 0;count < sequence.length(); count++){
                        if(!(Character.valueOf(seq[count]).equals('a'))&&
                                !(Character.valueOf(seq[count]).equals('g'))&&
                                !(Character.valueOf(seq[count]).equals('c'))&&
                                !(Character.valueOf(seq[count]).equals('t'))){
                            validSeq = false;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
        }

        //if sequence is valid fill frag with base seqence and pass the list to 
        //fragment list (fList) at position of insert
        if(validSeq){
            fList.moveTo(pos);
            frag.moveToStart();
            for(int count = 0;count < sequence.length(); count++){            
                frag.insert(seq[count]);
            }

            fList.insert(frag);
            System.out.print(fList.getValue());
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Invalid Sequence: not stored   ");
        }
    }
```

but I've checked the array and it seems to be storing the sequence properly

Comment: Post the code of your list implementation, or consider using the standard ArrayList

Comment: the singly linked list given to us is the one we are supposed to use, which i why this has got me so stuck

Comment: Could you post the whole method where the error is happening?

Comment: Just curious, what do you need `frag` for? Why don't insert into `fList` directly? Also, frag.insert(list) sends the parameter of type `SLList`, but there is only one insert and it takes E. I don't quite understand what's going on here

Comment: well i thought i was filling frag with sequence where each letter was store in it's own node, then that instance of frag would be passed into a single node of fList but when I use the method on sequence attacgatctgcacaagatcct i get cccccccccccccccccccccc for output and i know the array is properly storing the chars so it must be messing up where its storing the sequence in one of the two lists

Comment: You mean fList is defined as SLList<SLList> ? Is frag correct before you inserting it into fList?

Comment: yep it frag that's messing up, in the for loop where seq[count] is inserted into frag

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's actually kind of funny:

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    curr = head;
    for(int i=0; i<listSize; i++) {
      sb.append(curr.next().toString());
    }
    return "[" + sb.toString() + "]";
```

You're not incrementing the `curr`, so printing the same element `curr.next()` over and over again.

You also may have the wrong order there, hence `curr.next` is one before last instead of one after the first, but that's another issue.

I believe it should be like that:

```
  for(int count = 0;count < sequence.length(); count++){            
      frag.append(seq[count]);                    
  }
```

So probably the lists are almost OK, just the output is wrong.